# How I configure shell sqlplus to oracle

Tags: shell, sqlplus

I'm working in a new developer environment. How I set connection with oracle, because I need to execute any scripts, but I received the message: SQLPLUS NOT FOUND :/

Answer (score 1):

you need to add $ORACLE_HOME/bin into your PATH. and check if $ORACLE_HOME is defined first. If it's not ,define it (just the root folder of your oracle client).

If you don't have an oracle client installed you need to install one

Comment: `locate sqlplus` may be helpful to identify `ORACLE_HOME`

Comment: My Oracle Home is a root folder in my oracle client ?

Comment: ORACLE_HOME is a variable that need to be set up, and it's value is THE root folder of your oracle client. Once this variable is set up, what you need to do is to add to the PATH environment variable a new value (I think you can append at the end of the current PATH value using semi-colon, but check that out): $ORACLE_HOME/bin  this will tell your machine that in the "bin" folder of your oracle client there are some executable file. One of this is sqlplus, so from that moment on you'll be able to execute slqplus from everywhere.